# How to calculate rows and cols of JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea, dimension

I have a JFrame of dimension 600,700 and want to add a JTextArea in the whole frame size but don't know how to calculate the JTextArea rows and  cols from JFrame dimension ..

Comment: you can just add jtextrea, within a scrollpane, at center of borderlayout of the jframe and it will take full size of jframe, as and when jframe will expand

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can better understand your problem. As it already said by @Optional you should use layout manager like [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) because component that is added to its center gets the maximum available space.